# JqGrid Assigning Custom id to rows and cells

Tags: jqgrid

How can I assign the custom id's to JQGrid row and cells. I am using *`datatype: "local"`*. Is there some thing to do with *`key`* in `_columnModel_`.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to declare any ID to cell , instead you can use name property as ID. To access cell data you can use name property defined in colModel.

You can define your colModel like this:

```
  colModel: [{ name: 'myname', index: 'myname', width: 100, align: 'left', editable: false, search: true },
             { name: 'roll', index: 'roll', width: 100, align: 'left', editable: false, search: false, true}
         ],
```

...
And to access row details you can use below codes in onCellSelect method...

```
 ,onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent, target)
  {
     var rowData = $(this).jqGrid("getRowData", rowid);
     var g_myName = rowData.myname;
   }
```

Comment: in `ColModel` where are you specifying the id for the row or cell.
For example I want to give _aa_1_ to _first row_, _aa_2_ to _second row and so on_.

Comment: You need id in column to access the row right?? then that can be done through name property. See the usages of the same in OnCellSelect method... @ozil

Comment: Can I give my own id's to rows and cell if yes then how??